# Cant connect to Content Porter 2009 SP2

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

We have a DTAP environment, the same Tridion versions and hotfixes are installed on all servers. When I try to use Content Porter on the Acceptance or Production environment, I get the following error:

```
SDL Content Porter 2009 SP2

Could not find SDL Content Porter 2009 SP2 server on SDL Tridion Content Manager server localhost.
```

On Develop and Test there is no issue.

The Tridion server is 2011 SP1 - 1

Comment: Are you running the CP client directly on the CM servers? And can you validate that you have installed the CP Server on Acceptance and Production?

Comment: Yes i am running the CP client on te CM server. 

and i see "SDL Content Porter Server 2009 SP2 15.6 MB" in the windows Programs and Features on the production server.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced this issue many times and because of one of the issues mentioned below:

- The Content Porter Server 2009 SP2 is not installed on the environment to which you are trying to connect
- The SDL Tridion Content Porter Service is Stopped or not functioning correctly - Check in the list of Windows Service if it is running properly **(or in fact Restart the SDL Tridion Content Porter Service and retry)** - Most of the time I faced this issue because of this
- User ID / Pwd that you are using absolutely do not have access on CMS - You can check that by logging in to the CME
- User Credential are wrong because your CMS is configured as Windows Authentication but Content Porter is configured as LDAP authentication OR vice-versa - Just check on your Server in IIS in the Authentication tab and accordingly use the correct authentication

In addition, If you have access on the Server you may try by running your Content Porter client on the Server itself and then try connecting using the same user; if it works, then you need to check for any network related as well as folder permission related issues.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Pankaj's suggestion above, you might want to check if any other version of the content porter client is already installed in the client machine. 
If you have a different version of the client installed in your system, you might want to remove the program and re-install CP client again.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the ImportExportService was running under a default application pool, which was set to classic mode. I found this by browsing the service web application.

@Pankaj Thanks for your elaborate awnser. It made me think about looking for an authentication issue.

Note that Tridion 2011 SP1 - 1 uses IIS and doesn't have a seperate content porter service